# await não aguarda execução da promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

Pensei que havia entendido o funcionamento da função assíncrona com `await`. No meu entendimento o `await` aguardava o `resolve` da `Promise` para dar continuidade para à seguinte.

Para testar esse funcionamento, criei duas funções que retornam uma promessa e incluí um temporizador (simulando acesso a base de dados). Percebi que o código foi executado de forma assíncrona, ignorando o `await`.

```
function getSenha() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                setTimeout( function() {
                    console.log( 'Executa uma vez após 9 segundos.' );
                  }, 9000 );                    
                resolve("RET_SENHA");
    });
};

function getMensagem() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        setTimeout( function() {
            console.log( 'Executa uma vez após 1 segundo.' );
            }, 1000 );          
            resolve("RET_MSG");
    });
}


async function montaMensagem() {
    const senha = await getSenha();
    const msg = await getMensagem();

    console.log('Senha: ', senha);
    console.log('Mensagem: ', msg);
}
montaMensagem();
```

Segue o resultado:

```
Senha:  RET_SENHA
Mensagem:  RET_MSG
Executa uma vez após 1 segundo.
Executa uma vez após 9 segundos.
```

O correto não seria:

```
Executa uma vez após 9 segundos.
Executa uma vez após 1 segundo.
Senha:  RET_SENHA
Mensagem:  RET_MSG
```

Com a consulta no Banco:

```
getSenha() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
            let connection = AtendimentoDB.connect();
            let sql = "select * from senha";

            connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    resolve(results);
                }
            });
            connection.end();
        });
    };

getMensagem() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
            let connection = AtendimentoDB.connect();
            let sql = "SELECT mensagem FROM configuracao;";
            connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    resolve(results);
                }
            });
            connection.end();

        });
};

async function montaMensagem() {
    const senha = await getSenha();
    const msg = await getMensagem();

    console.log('Senha: ', senha);
    console.log('Mensagem: ', msg);
}
```

Comment: tente colocar o async na função getMensagem() e getSenha()

Comment: @OtavioCapel, valeu pela dica, mas não funcionou. Pelo que entendi, somente a função que vai usar o await precisa ser async, estou certo?

Comment: Você não precisa colocar os resolve dentro do timeout? Ele de fato executa a function do timeout após determinado período, mas em quanto isso, ele continua executando o código (no caso o resolve)

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui colocando o resolve dentro do timeout e de fato houve o resultado esperado, seria isso?

Comment: O certo não seria colocar o "resolve("RET_SENHA")" dentro da function do timeout?

Comment: @LeonardoButa, você está certo. O correto seria incluir dentro do setTimeout. Obrigado pelo retorno.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: O problema não está na função assíncrona e/ou no `await`. Como mencionado pelo [@Leonardo Buta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/131001/leonardo-buta) nos comentários da pergunta, problema está na sua implementação dos exemplos `getSenha` e `getMessage`, já que o `resolve()` deveria ter sido chamado dentro do `setTimeout`.

---

Assumindo que tanto `getSenha` quanto `getMessage` fazem exatamente a mesma coisa, irei exemplificar o motivo da situação usando a primeira função apresentada:

> ```
> function getSenha() {
>   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
>     setTimeout( function() {
>         console.log( 'Executa uma vez após 9 segundo.' );
>     }, 9000 );                    
>     resolve("RET_SENHA");
>   });
> };
> ```

Nela, podemos afirmar que o `resolve()` está fora do `setTimeout`, o que faz com que a promessa seja resolvida imediatamente após a sua chamada, fazendo com que somente o `console.log` aguarde os 9 segundos. Essa resolução imediata da `Promise` nos dá a **impressão** de que o `await` não funciona (já que a promessa é resolvida instantaneamente e não temos essa percepção). **Na realidade, o `await` parou a execução da função por um número extremamente pequeno de tempo**.

---

O exemplo mostra abaixo a diferença entre colocar o `resolve` dentro e fora do `setTimeout`:

```js
function withinSetTimeout() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Console.log: [1] (Dentro do setTimeout)')

      // Note que o `resolve` está dentro do `setTimeout`. Isso faz com que
      // a Promise só seja resolvida quando o tempo de espera (2s) acabar.
      resolve('[1] De dentro do setTimeout!')
    }, 2000)
  })
}

function outsideSetTimeout() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Console.log: [2] (Dentro do setTimeout)')
    }, 2000)

    // Por estar fora do `setTimeout`, a Promise será resolvida
    // imediatamente (não haverá nenhum aguardo).
    resolve('[2] De fora do setTimeout!')
  })
}

async function ex1() {
  const result1 = await withinSetTimeout()
  console.log('[1] Resultado:', result1)
}

async function ex2() {
  const result2 = await outsideSetTimeout()
  console.log('[2] Resultado:', result2)
}

ex1()
ex2()
```

---

E para esclarecer: o `await` para a execução dentro da função assíncrona até que a `Promise` que ele esteja aguardando seja resolvida ou rejeitada. Essa afirmação [pode ser confirmada através da documentação relativa ao `await` na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Veja a demonstração abaixo:

```js
// A função abaixo cria uma função que pausa o código dentro de uma função
// assíncrona por um dado tempo.
function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  })
}

// Demonstração da pausa causada pelo `await`:
async function main() {
  console.log('[1] Serei executado imediatamente!')
  await wait(800)
  console.log('[2] Fui executado após 800ms após o primeiro!')
  await wait(900)
  console.log('[3] Fui executado 900ms após o segundo!')
  await wait(1000)
  console.log('[4] Fui executado 1s após o terceiro!')
}

main()
```

---

## Respostas aos comentários

Em resposta aos comentários da pergunta:

> Pelo que entendi, somente a função que vai usar o await precisa ser async, estou certo?

Sim! Somente a função que vai usar o `await` precisa ser marcada como assíncrona. Em outros casos, essa marcação será desnecessária, apesar de não ter nenhum impacto negativo no código.

> Na situação real será uma consulta ao banco de dados, não teria como utilizar um timeout.

Nesse caso, o `await` irá aguardar a consulta ao banco de dados, esperando o tempo da consulta. Nesse tempo, a execução da função assíncrona será pausada. O `setTimeout` no seu exemplo foi essa demora da consulta, e portanto, o `resolve` deveria ter sido colocado dentro do `setTimeout`, representando o momento em que os dados serão resolvidos.

> Se a consulta ao banco será aguardada, porque o mesmo não aconteceu com o timeout?

A consulta ao banco será aguardada por que a `Promise` só será resolvida quando a *query* devidamente realizada e devolver os dados, que serão resolvidos pela promessa. É como se fosse algo assim:

1. Você chama o método `db.query`;
2. Ele realiza a *query* no seu banco de dados;
3. Assim que os dados são resolvidos, a promessa é resolvida.
4. Em caso de erros, a promessa é rejeitada.

Você não fez essa simulação corretamente, porque como expliquei logo no começo da resposta, você teria que ter colocado o `resolve()` dentro do `setTimeout` (o que simularia o tempo de espera da *query*). Como você chamou o `resolve` fora do `setTimeout`, a promessa foi resolvida imediatamente.

Comment: Luiz, obrigado pela excelente resposta, mas ainda fiquei com uma duvida. Se a consulta ao banco será aguardada, porque o mesmo não aconteceu com o timeout? Podemos falar amanhã ?

Comment: Editei a pergunta. Veja se ficou mais claro.

Comment: Luiz, vamos lá. A minha dúvida deve ser em relação a algo muito básico, estou iniciando. Entendi a sua colocação, mas a minha única dúvida é: tanto o timeout quanto a query são dois processos, porque a query interrompe o processamento e o timeout passada direto. Vou incluir um JSFiddle para detalhar a minha dúvida.

Comment: Luiz, no meu entendimento o fato de utilizar await na chamada da função, isso faria com que a função fosse executada de forma sincrona, ou seja, linha a linha aguardando a finalização de cada linha. No exemplo do setTimeout, achei que deveria aguardar os segundos, exibir a mensagem no console e só depois retornar o resolve. Por que não foi executado dessa maneira? Essa é a minha dúvida. Valeu pela força.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92948/discussion-between-luiz-felipe-and-developer).

Comment: Luiz, com a sua ajuda consegui esclarecer a minha dúvida. Agora só mesmo praticando para que o conceito seja assimilado. Obrigado.

Comment: Luiz, alterei aminha resposta ao LeonardoButa, ele estava realmente correto.