# Aguardar a consulta ao banco para dar retorno

Tags: javascript, sqlite

Estou fazendo uma consulta ao banco SQLite.
Porém a função acaba dando retorno antes da consulta ser realizada.
Estou tentando solucionar isso utilizando um tipo de controle enquanto a consulta não prossegue. Tem alguma forma de resolver essa questão?

Meu código está abaixo:

```
model.executarSql = function (sSql) {
   var bExec = false; // Controle se pode prosseguir ou não

   db.transaction(function(tx){
      tx.executeSql(sSql, [], function(txs, results){
         var aRet  = []; // Array bidimensional com todos os resultados
         var aItem = []; // Array com um resultado por vez

         for(it = 0; it < results.rows.length; it++){
            while (aItem.length > 0){ aItem.pop() }; // limpar o array

            for(cp = 0; cp < results.rows.item(it).length; cp++){
               aItem.push(results.rows.item(it)[cp]);
            }

            aRet.push(aItem);
         }

         bExec = true;
      });
   });

   while (!bExec){
      // Aguardar a consulta ao banco
   };

   return aRet;
};
```

Comment: Rodrigo, o Javascript trabalha de forma assíncrona. Sugiro que você de uma olhada em `callback` e `Promise`. Tive o mesmo problema no entendimento [await](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/379766/await-n%C3%A3o-aguarda-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-promise-resolvido) [Callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo, sugiro você usar uma estratégia de promises do javascript.

Porque ai o dado vindo do banco virá dentro da resolução da sua promise e nesse contexto você irá utilizar o dado ou manipula-lo.

```
function consultaBanco (msg, who, timeout) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("Executa a sua consulta")
})
}
consultaBanco().then((resultaDaConsulta) =>
 "Aqui você você tem garantia que seu dado existira antes de manipular"
).catch((msg) => {
"Aqui é você terá o objeto de error caso aconteça"})
```

Espero que tenha ajudado. Boa sorte.