# Await dentro de uma função síncrona

Tags: javascript

Fiz um programa que treina uma rede neural pra jogar jogo da velha com o usuário. Preciso resgatar o valor retornado pelo método `this.academy.step`, que contém a posição da próxima jogada do computador, porém, ao invés do valor desejado, meu código está retornando uma `promise`.

```
var result = (async() => 
        await this.academy.step([{teacherName: this.teacher, agentsInput: inputs}]))();
```

Comment: poste o `this.academy.step`? também

Comment: Você não pode aguardar o retorno de uma promessa em uma função síncrona. Vejo duas opções: converter a função para `async` ou usar o _callback_ dentro do `then` para acessar o valor resolvido da promessa na função síncrona. Para saber mais, veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/379212/como-atribuir-o-resultado-de-uma-promise-a-uma-vari%c3%a1vel/379215#379215) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/379766/await-n%c3%a3o-aguarda-execu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-da-promise-resolvido/379769#379769).

Comment: Virgilio Novic este método eu peguei da biblioteca ReImproveJS

Comment: Não existe await dentro de funções síncronas, leia apenas os dois primeiros parágrafos: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await